# How escape text with accent in xpath selenium and java?

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, selenium-ide

For example:
I have a `text = "Non Spécifié"` and I need escape the accents to match the `xpath` with `locator` related in the `page`

```
option = By.xpath("//div[./input[contains(@name, text )]]");
```

Returns an `error` because not match the `xpath`.

in UI is displayed as Non Spécifié: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwXO4.png)

What could be the solution?

Comment: Can you attach the HTML snippet? Mayve you want contains(text(), text) instead of contains(@name, text )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi please try like below it will work 
use **java.text.Normalizer**

```
// your accent string 
String text = "Non Spécifié";
System.out.println("Earlier value : "+text);

// after using Normalizer
String string = Normalizer.normalize(text, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
// now compare each character against a letter.
String normalString  = string.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
System.out.println("Accent changed to normal string : "+ normalString);

// note If your text is in unicode.use like below 
// String normalString = string.replaceAll("\\p{M}", "");

// now you can use above in your xpath like below 
option = By.xpath("//div[./input[contains(@name, normalString )]]");
```

hope this helps you

Comment: returns failed:

Earlier value : Non Spécifié

,Accent changed to normal string : Non SpAcifiA

       //div[./input[contains(@name, 'non spacifia')]]

       I tried the following text and works in xpath, but I can not use text hard-code: 

if (text.contains("Non Sp")) {
            text = "Non Sp\u00E9cifi\u00E9";
            System.out.println("text value " + text);
        }

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
//*[contains(translate(@name,'áàâäéèêëíìîïóòôöúùûü','aaaaeeeeiiiioooouuuu'),'Non Specifie')]
```

The main idea to use built in xpath function. In theory it should be enough.

Good luck.